# I do not understand "hit on the wheeze over a curry"

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang

I cannot understand the meaning of this sentence.
This is in the article titled as "Let England shake" (*[The Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/britain/21620243-scotlands-independence-referendum-has-opened-cracks-united-kingdom-let-england-shake)*, Sep 27th 2014) — article about Scotland's independence referendum

> *The prime minister reportedly hit on the wheeze over a curry with George Osborne, the chancellor of the exchequer, the night before.*

I do not understand the meaning of the word "curry" in this context. Is it Indian food?

Comment: I'd say you are correct - Indian food.

Comment: "[A dish of meat, vegetables, etc., cooked in an Indian-style sauce of strong spices](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curry)"

Answer (score 6):

> The prime minister reportedly hit on the wheeze over a curry with
>   George Osborne, the chancellor of the exchequer, the night before.

The prime minister came up with the plan over a meal of Indian food with George Osborne the night before.

Hit on = to (suddenly) get an idea

Wheeze = British slang for 'plan, idea, ruse, trick'.

Over a meal = (to discuss something) while having a meal together; "over a curry" is over a meal consisting of that cuisine.

Comment: I would say it's also being derogatory (to the politicians) in this instance. Rather going through a correct process of formulating ideas in parliament and discussing it with relevant people, the writer is implying that the idea was conceived at the last minute by the PM and Osborne while they were enjoying a few beers and curry at the end of a long day. Probably scribbled down on the back of a serviette/napkin (depending on how posh you are - probably napkin in their case). The UK has many Indian restaurants and 'going for a curry' is a pretty normal pastime for lots of people.

Comment: Yes, you can be fairly sure it's meant to be derogatory by the injected "reportedly".  If "wheeze" were not enough.